# Parse Server REST API - Group by and Sum

Tags: rest, parse-server

Is it possible to group by and sum values using the Parse Server REST API.

e.g. https://parseapi.back4app.com/classes/myclass?groupby=name&sum=score

If i have a table of 100k rows i would not like to let the client download all the result in order to perform a sum of the values.

Example Source:

```
name    | score
frank   | 50
frank   | 20
ben     | 30
```

Result:

```
name    | score
frank   | 70
ben     | 30
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible.  According to the [Parse REST API Guide for Aggregate Queries](https://docs.parseplatform.org/rest/guide/#aggregate-queries), you can perform a **group by** with an **aggregate count** operation with the following query string:

```
https://<parse_server_url>/parse/aggregate/myclass?group={"objectId": { "name" : "$name"},"total":{"$sum":"$score"}}
```

The response from the server would be as follows:

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "total": 30,
            "objectId": {
                "name": "ben"
            }
        },
        {
            "total": 70,
            "objectId": {
                "name": "frank"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**Explanation**
The key is to use the **/aggregate** URI rather than the **/classes** URI to get this functionality via the Parse REST API.

The objectID defines the "group by" fields.  You can put multiple fields in this list if you wish to group by more than one field.

Example:

```
"objectId": { "groupByField1" : "$nameOfField1", "groupByField2" : "$nameOfField2"}
```

If you wish to filter some records out before grouping and aggregating, you can include the "match" parameter in your query string.

Example:

```
https://<parse_server_url>/parse/aggregate/myclass?match={"name":"frank"}&group={"objectId": { "name" : "$name"},"total":{"$sum":"$score"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Groups and sum are not implemented as the backing database in mongodb and this falls into the aggregation pipelines. We’re currently looking into it for groups.

Answer (score -1):

Migrate to [PostgREST](https://github.com/begriffs/postgrest) where you have PostgreSQL, a database that is capable of such trivial things :)